# Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

How to remove this error
Gas estimation error with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail.  Internal JSON-RPC error.
i am not understanding why this error is there,
mainly in this two functions

```
function buyTokens() public payable {
  uint tokenAmount = msg.value * rate;
  require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= tokenAmount); token.transfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);
  emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, address(token), tokenAmount, rate);
}

function sellTokens(uint _amount) public {
  require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount);
  uint etherAmount = _amount / rate;
  require(address(this).balance >= etherAmount);
  token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
  msg.sender.transfer(etherAmount);
  emit TokensSold(msg.sender, address(token), _amount, rate);
}
```